# Is it good to use my with loops in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have seen many piece of code in many standard books where my is being used in loops like below.

TYPE 1-

```
foreach my $mykey ( keys %myhash) {
......
}
```

or

```
while(my $line = <$filehandle> ) {
.....
}
```

Here we are declaring variable for each key of the hash or for each line.Is it a good idea?

In C/C++/Java we used to declare the variable first then we use it. So if I follow that policy then above code should be as below.

TYPE 2-

```
my $mykey;
foreach $mykey (keys %myhash) {
....
}
```

or

```
my $line;
while($line = <$filehandle> ) {
....
}
```

It will speedup the code execution( I think) because as per context we decide what type of operation can be applied on variable and what will be its behavior.

But I have seen TYPE 1 code mostly in Perl. So I think I am missing some perl concept. Someone please throw light on it.

If you are going to say that it is declared/associated to scope once and then incremented only then please provide some documentation. I could not get it anywhere. I understand that scope of the variable will be different in both the cases.

@http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29--
The my operator declares the listed variables to be lexically confined to the enclosing block, conditional (if/unless/elsif/else), loop (for/foreach/while/until/continue), subroutine, eval, or do/require/use'd file.

will variable association using my will be done in each step?

Comment: `for (int i=...` is quite common in C and C++ too.

Comment: yes it is. But initialization happens only once.

Comment: Only one variable is created and its value is overwritten with each loop iteration. Perl is clever enough to figure that out

Comment: Hye knittl -- how perl does this? Yes I have also assumed the same. But can you please provide some documentation for the same.I could not find any :(

Comment: @virus: In your post you write that you had the opposite assumption.

Comment: @Knittl- I said if I take java/C/C++ style only. I want to know something different. I have added last paragraph to my question to avoid different discussion

Comment: _It will speedup the code execution_ → no, looking at the opcode tree there's no speed penalty in using `for my $i (...)`.

Comment: @SlavenRezic: Actually, `for my $i (...)` is the fastest possible `for` loop even faster than `for (...)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a benchmark:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my @list = ('abc')x1_000_000;

my $count = -2;
cmpthese($count, {
    'inside' => sub {
        for my $elem(@list) { $elem = '' }
    },
    'outside' => sub {
        my $elem;
        for $elem(@list) { $elem = '' }
    },
});
```

**Result:**

```
          Rate outside  inside
outside 14.3/s      --      0%
inside  14.3/s      0%      --
```

As you can see, there're no differences in term of speed.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, the biggest difference between

```
while(my $line = <$filehandle> ) {
.....
}
```

and

```
my $line 
while($line = <$filehandle> ) {
.....
}
```

lies in **scope**, much more than optimisation for speed or execution time.

In the first case, `$line` is only visible in the while loop. After that, it goes out of scope, you get your memory back, and you have less chance for mistakes (by using a `$line` later and not getting an error.

Source: see this [perldoc about for loops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops).

Comment: I want to know something different. I have added last paragraph to my question to avoid different discussion

Answer (score 5):

Saying:

```
foreach my $mykey ( keys %myhash) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
while(my $line = <$filehandle> ) {
  ...
}
```

confines the scope of variables `$mykey` and `$line` to the `foreach` and `while` loops respectively.

You might also want to say [`use strict 'vars'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html).

Comment: I want to know something different. I have added last paragraph to my question to avoid different discussion.

Comment: @virus You seem to be looking for [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29).

Comment: @http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29-- The my operator declares the listed variables to be lexically confined to the enclosing block, conditional (if/unless/elsif/else), loop (for/foreach/while/until/continue), subroutine, eval, or do/require/use'd file.

will variable association using my will be done in each step?

Comment: @virus `will variable association using my will be done in each step?`  No. It only affects the scope.  Within the scope, the value would change and would be visible.  That's it.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what others have said about scope, if you don't use a lexical loop iterator in a `for` loop you may encounter code like:

```
my $i;
for $i (1..10) {
    last if check_something($i);
}
print $i;
```

This looks like it will print some value between 1 and 10, depending on the logic in `check_something`. In fact, it will always print `undef` because it is interpreted more like:

```
my $i;
{
    local $i;
    for $i (1..10) {
        last if check_something($i);
    }
}
print $i;
```

More detail in the [Perl::Critic RequireLexicalLoopIterators policy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/Variables/RequireLexicalLoopIterators.pm).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the speed can be a issue in both approaches as it will be minimal(if its not run a million times, even that will be not much).

Type 1, will always clear the variable everytime loop is run.

Type 2, it wont happen everytime at runtime.